# SSIS Package Opening in Visual Studio 2022 as Code

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I recently installed Visual Studio 2022 and SSMS 19.1.  I am trying to open a SSIS package that I previously had opened and saved in Visual Studio 2012 via Visual Studio Solution Explorer in a New Solution that I created.  It opens the .dtsx package, but it opens the XML code, not the Control Flow, Data Flow tabs etc.  Am I missing configurations in the new install of Visual Studio 2022?

Thank you.

I tried finding resources on the Internet, but yet to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the SQL Server Integration Services add-in. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices

There's a troubleshooting guide if you need it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/ssis-vs2022-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.  Packages are opening as XML instead of the SSIS designer even when I select the "View Designer" option.  I've tried repairing the extension which did not work.  I then uninstalled the extention and reinstalled which also did not work.

I have a non-SSIS project (web) which I think has caused a conflict.  In the web project I have a dtsx file which I set to open as xml.  This seems to have someone carried over to the SSIS project.

Note that the SSIS project was working fine for a while.  I was able to open and edit packages in the designer.

Any idea how to get the SSIS project to open packages in the ssis designer instead of XML?  Seems like there must be a setting somewhere controlling which designer is used.